# Need Text Correction feature

Tags: spell-checking

I need a text correction feature which can check for both the spelling and grammatical mistakes in the user written paragraph. I researched a bit but was able to find solutions which can check for the spell mistakes but not supporting the grammatical corrections / suggestions.

Do any one know such library / api which is suitable for both grammatical and spelling suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Two big names seem to be [Language Tool](http://languagetool.org/) and [After the Deadline](http://afterthedeadline.com/).

Comment: Thanks Amadan. But neither of the above gives 100% result for grammatical errors. It works well for spell errors and some grammatical errors but doesn't point out all the grammatical errors.

Comment: Human language is still not perfectly understood by linguists. It is extremely hard to make a halfway good grammar analysis software; it is currently pretty much impossible to make a software that will point out *all* grammatical errors. Best you can aim for is to pick the one which makes less errors than others.